# How to use callbackJS in shinyWidgets?

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

I used to use in Shinyalert, but because there are some bugs I try to use in shinyWidgets (ask_confirmation).
In Shinyalert I used callbackJS to know if the user click on OK or on Cancel, but it is not working
in ask_confirmation.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ask_confirmation(
    "form1",
    title = " ",
    type = "question",
    btn_labels = c("Cancel", "OK"),
    allowEscapeKey = TRUE,
    closeOnClickOutside = TRUE,
    html = TRUE,
    #######################
    #this one is not woking
    callbackJS =      "  
    function(x) {
      if (x !== false) {
      alert('t');
      }
    else{
    alert('ttt');
    }
}
    
    ",
    ######################
    text =  
      div(HTML("
    
<form style = ' display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center' action=''>
<div style='border: 5px  black;'>
<input type='text'name='add_nosha_tohen' autocomplete='off' id='add_nosha_tohen' value=''   dir='rtl' style='border-color: black; font-size: 12px;height: 45px; width: 400px; display: block;'/></input>
</div>
</form>
"
      ))
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any idea how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `callbackJS` argument in `ask_confirmation`. To do a callback, and run JS code, you can do:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)
ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    ask_confirmation(
        "form1",
        title = " ",
        type = "question",
        btn_labels = c("Cancel", "OK"),
        allowEscapeKey = TRUE,
        closeOnClickOutside = TRUE,
        html = TRUE,
######################
text =  
    div(HTML("
<form style = ' display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center' action=''>
<div style='border: 5px  black;'>
<input type='text'name='add_nosha_tohen' autocomplete='off' id='add_nosha_tohen' value=''   dir='rtl' style='border-color: black; font-size: 12px;height: 45px; width: 400px; display: block;'/></input>
</div>
</form>
"
    ))
    )
    
    observeEvent(input$form1, {
        if(is.null(input$form1)) runjs("alert('NULL');")
        else if (input$form1) runjs("alert('true');")
        else runjs("alert('false');")
    }, ignoreNULL = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]